# Read/write a file with ADT

Tags: java, android, adt

I need to create an N-line ascii file. 
Read the N lines during run time.
Manipulate them 
and write back to the same file.

What is a good way of doing this with ADT? I **tried** writing to a file in assets folder which I later realized is not editable during run time.

Comment: Resource files are non-editable after they are packaged into an apk. You can use file I/O, sharedpreferences or sqllite for persisting data on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pull the file you want to edit, edit it and then push it back with ADT. However, you don't have permission to access the folders in the device memory from outside (unless your device is rooted and you have changed the file permissions to be able to read & write). So this means that through ADT you don't have access to the assets of a specific Application.

One idea is to transfer the assets you want to the SDcard after the first launch and use the resources from there. then you can pull and push specific files with ADB through console od the file explorer in Eclipse in DDMS.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to create a new file in sdcard using standard IO functions? Following idea didn' t seem to work: String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/file.txt"; File f = new File(fileName); if(!f.exists()) {  f.createNewFile(); }

Comment: didn't seem to work why? do you get an exception? do you have the write_external_storage permission defined in your manifest?

Comment: Manifest permissions have to be given for "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE". Then above snippet is used for external file creation. Then, standard IO manipulation can be done as described here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaIO/article.html. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You just need Write_external_storage. read is not needed if you have the write permission

Comment: In my case, I needed both READ and WRITE for both ADK emulator and the mobile device. It didn't work otherwise. Seemed strange to me as well. I will elaborate more on that later. Quick and dirty part is done for now :)